How to create unique ids in xl sheets or R
I am creating unique ids on excel based on several variables like, name of the farmer, name of the field, hectares- to see how many times these variables match, and whether these fields could again be used for certain crops that do not prosper under monocropping. I created some manually intuitively- like "MT18MG3" for "Mattern, Tobias"(name of the farmer) "1.8 ha"(hectares) "Mittelgewanne 3."(field name) the problem now is, there are several of these fields with these names, and i dont know if i am repeating the same unique id after a few hundred entries.
Now can i do this on any other software like R studio where i get these values with accuracy?
I used VBA, concatenate, hash values etc on xl, but after generating a few unique ids the way i like, xl is either repeating some values, or creating some that make no sense whatsoever.

Could you just concatenate the row number (e.g., 1-xxx, 2-xxx) at the beginning?

Is it really useful to create the IDs containing some logic? To identify a row of data, usually a unique number is the easiest you can do. If you want to search for rows with specific characteristics, you need to look into your data (database) anyhow, using filtering, sql statements or some code. You probably will not query the data by just looking for specific IDs (3 character is an "A" or the like).

@FunThomas I understand what you are saying. Perhaps that is the best way to do. can you perhaps suggest the way to create a unique id instead of the specific i wanted it to be?

I would personally use vba to solve this problem.
It is possible to create a module where it takes data directly from the cells and behaves as a function, and I would also add the possibility of a suffix with the timestamp thus making unique ids.
How the Function Works:
First, the function takes the main variables: the first two characters of the farmer's name, the field size (without the decimal point), the first two characters of the field name, and the field number. All this is concatenated to form the ID.
For example:
farmer = "Mattern, Tobias" 

field = "Mittelgewanne"  

hectares = 1.8

field number = 3 

generated ID would look like:
Ma18Mi3

Now, if you want to ensure that the ID is truly unique, you can opt to add a timestamp (the current date and time) at the end. This is useful when there is a risk of repetition. With the timestamp, the ID would look like this:
Ma18Mi3_17120030

In this case, the timestamp represents the day, hour, minute, and second (feel free to add or remove fields if preferred) when the ID was generated, ensuring it never repeats.
Implementing the Function in VBA:
To use this function in Excel, you need to add the VBA code to a module:
the code below:
Function GerarIDUnico(farmer As String, hectares As Double, field_name As String, field_number As Integer, Optional incluirTimestamp As Boolean = False) As String
    ' This function generates a unique ID based on the provided variables and optionally adds a timestamp suffix for uniqueness

    Dim firstTwoFarmer As String
    Dim hectaresNoDot As String
    Dim firstTwoField As String
    Dim uniqueID As String
    Dim timestampSuffix As String

    ' Get the first two characters of the farmer's name
    firstTwoFarmer = Left(farmer, 2)
    
    ' Convert hectares to string and remove the decimal point
    hectaresNoDot = Replace(CStr(hectares), ".", "")
    
    ' Get the first two characters of the field name
    firstTwoField = Left(field_name, 2)
    
    ' Concatenate the values to create the unique ID
    uniqueID = firstTwoFarmer & hectaresNoDot & firstTwoField & field_number
    
    ' If the incluirTimestamp parameter is true, add a timestamp suffix
    If incluirTimestamp Then
        ' you can change to yyyymmddhhmmss for year and month 
        timestampSuffix = Format(Now(), "ddhhmmss")
        uniqueID = uniqueID & "_" & timestampSuffix
    End If

    ' Return the final ID
    GerarIDUnico = uniqueID
End Function

How to Use:
Without the timestamp (normal mode):
=GerarIDUnico(A2, B2, C2, D2, FALSE)

With the timestamp (to ensure uniqueness):
=GerarIDUnico(A2, B2, C2, D2, TRUE)

The function is very flexible, so you can choose when to activate the timestamp or not.
You can test the code online here:
https://onlinegdb.com/tLydVR_Lj
Sorry, some translation error, my English is not the best

As I wrote as comment: Don't put logic into the ID. Just use a simple number.
(1) If you have an Excel sheet with data (but without IDs), you can use the following script to generate missing IDs. Put the code into a regular module.
Just adapt the column where you want to store the ID (currently, it assumes that you have the IDs in column A) and change the worksheet in the With-statement if your data doesn't live in the first sheet. Also, replace the "B" in .Range("B1").CurrentRegion with a column of your data that is always filled (eg the farmer name).
Global Const IDColumn = "A"

Sub GenerateAllIds()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  ' Change to your worksheet
        Dim row As Long, lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        For row = 2 To lastRow
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(row, IDColumn)) Then
                .Cells(row, IDColumn) = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(1, IDColumn).EntireColumn) + 1
            End If
        Next row
    End With
End Sub

You need to run the code only once, eg by pressing F5 in the VBA editor or by using the Macros dialog in Excel.
(2) If you fill in the sheet manually and want to add an ID to the row whenever new data is entered, put the following code into the Worksheet module of the sheet where your data is located:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Use error handler to ensure that events are switched on again
    On Error GoTo change_Exit
    
    ' disable events to prevent recursive calls.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Target.Parent      ' (Target.Parent is the active sheet)
        ' Allow to delete full rows or columns
        If Target.Columns.Count = .Columns.Count Or Target.Rows.Count = .Rows.Count Then GoTo change_Exit
    
        ' Not allowed to modify column A
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Cells(1, IDColumn).EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Don't modify the ID column."
            Application.Undo
            GoTo change_Exit
        End If
    
        ' Create IDs for newly entered data
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" And IsEmpty(.Cells(cell.row, IDColumn).Value) Then
                ' Create new ID
                .Cells(cell.row, IDColumn) = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(1, IDColumn).EntireColumn) + 1
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
    
change_Exit:
    ' enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

